# displaying imported figure has poor resolution

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to display imported figures in a matplotlib subplot inside a ipython notebook,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import numpy as np
img = mpimg.imread("image.png",format="png")
f, axarr = plt.subplots(1,2)

axarr[0].imshow(img)
axarr[1].imshow(img)
```

which kind of works but the displayed resolution is pretty poor. What am I missing here? When I use

```
from IPython.display import Image
displayImage(img)
```

it looks much better, but then I cant place  multiple figures in row.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Somehow increasing the standard figsize before reading the figure did the trick.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams.update({'figure.figsize': (30,30)})
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import numpy as np
img = mpimg.imread("image.png",format="png")
f, axarr = plt.subplots(1,2)

axarr[0].imshow(img)
axarr[1].imshow(img)
```